# xquery search:suggest where search term start with double quotes

Tags: xquery, marklogic, double-quotes, cts-search

I want to search marklogic for term that start with double quotes. i am using search-suggest.

term that i am searching is '"Independent'. When executed successfully, query should suggest multiple options with one option that is  '"Independent party'. But its not returning any suggestion. I can see that search-suggest is not finding term that start with double quote. Please suggest how can i fix it.

code is shared below.

```
let $options:=<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<additional-query>
 <cts:and-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:collection-query>
   <cts:uri>myCollection</cts:uri>
  </cts:collection-query>
  <cts:or-query>
   <cts:collection-query>
     <cts:uri>anotherCollection</cts:uri>
    </cts:collection-query>
  </cts:or-query>
 </cts:and-query>
</additional-query>
<term>
 <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
 <term-option>punctuation-sensitive</term-option>
 <empty apply="all-results">
 </empty>
</term>
<constraint name="myTargetItem">
 <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint" type="xs:string" facet="false">
 <element ns="---" name="targetItem">
</element>
</range>
</constraint>
</options>


let $searchTerm := '"Independent'
let $searchTerm := concat('"*',$searchTerm )
let $searchTerm :=  concat("myTargetItem", ':', $searchTerm )
return search:suggest($searchTerm , $options,20)
```

Actual Result
EMPTY

Expected
myTargetItem:""Independent"

Comment: Are you sure your additional query is correct? You may want to try removing that element completely and then testing it.

Comment: Yes @RobS.additional query is correct. its narrowing down search to my collections. probelm is that how can i search a term that start with double quote?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
let $options:=
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<additional-query>
 <cts:and-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:collection-query>
   <cts:uri>myCollection</cts:uri>
  </cts:collection-query>
  <cts:or-query>
   <cts:collection-query>
     <cts:uri>anotherCollection</cts:uri>
    </cts:collection-query>
  </cts:or-query>
 </cts:and-query>
</additional-query>
<default-suggestion-source>
  <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint" type="xs:string" 
    facet="false">
   <element ns="" name="targetItem"/>
  </range>
  <suggestion-option>case-insensitive</suggestion-option>
  <suggestion-option>punctuation-sensitive</suggestion-option>
</default-suggestion-source>
</options>


let $searchTerm := '"Independent'
let $searchTerm := concat('"*',$searchTerm )
let $searchTerm :=  concat("myTargetItem", ':', $searchTerm )
return search:suggest($searchTerm , $options,20)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. i had to change options  in order to execute it without error.i had to remove <suggestion-option> and added the term element as i already had originally. so, t executes and give result. it return me other three possible options that start with word 'Independent' but result doesn't include the option that start with double quote.  Please guide.

Comment: i think i need to manipulate search grammar. if you see, ' "Independent ', this double quote doesn't get treated as double quote. instead, search ignores it or consider it a phrase search. any comment about it?

Comment: While going through marklogic docs, i came to know that "You cannot specify a search that includes quotation character". Reference URL is https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_41181. so, i think thats the final answer to my query then :|

Comment: @nimTas Not sure offhand but you may be able to add <debug>true</debug> and see what's being run under the hood in your return. I'm very interested in this and will try to reproduce it if I have some time soon.

Comment: @nimTas That link also says " For example, in the DEFAULT grammar, you cannot search for a double quote (") because this is the quotation character." I emphasized the word default. So you may want to try adding <grammar>
  <quotation>#</quotation></grammar> to your search options.

Comment: yes @RobS. You are right. As per docs, we could have customize default grammar. But its deprecated now. still, there are some third party services available. but i don't think that will be a safe approach.  Reference url is "https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap5#id_38143". But may be i will try to customize, just to see how it will go. Then will share my experience